# How to pass on an extra variable along with AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, return

Need to run some code only after an AJAX response is received, and I need to pass on a certain variable to the destination function to make it happen.

Tried the below but it doesn't trigger the .done function like it would if we were returning only the ajax(not surprisingly).

```
function ajax_processor(passthrough_var,ordinary_var)
{
    //Some processing

    return [ passthrough_var, $.ajax({...}) ];
}

ajax_post_processor(array_item)
{
    console.log(array_item[0]);
    console.log(array_item[1]);
}

ajax_processor("Foo","Bar").done(ajax_post_processor);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have `ajax_processor` return a promise that resolves to an array containing the response and the passed variable. Something like

```
function ajax_processor(passthrough_var,ordinary_var)
{
    return $.ajax({...}).then(response => [passthrough_var, response]);
}

function ajax_post_processor(array_item)
{
    console.log(array_item[0]);
    console.log(array_item[1]);
}

ajax_processor("Foo","Bar").done(ajax_post_processor);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Just for understanding sake, is there also a way to do that without using an arrow function?

Comment: Of course you can use a “normal” function. JavaScript only cares that it is *a* function.